# How do I disable automatic screen locking in Xubuntu?i have tried many ways but still not working

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen, lock, light-locker

After about 10 minutes, Xubuntu the latest version goes to sleep by itself although I have changed the power setting and I put everything on never, besides I have disables locker program in startup application via setting manager but it still does not work and there is nothing with the name of light-locker here to kill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the lock tab under screen saver (which in in applications off a right click of mouse on the XFCE desktop)

Answer (score 2):

## I'VE FINALLY FOUND IT

#### PLAIN AND SIMPLE

Open the screensaver menu and uncheck all the lock options, and also the power options as well as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Caffeine** Indicator might help:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install caffeine
```